# Write Array To Entire Line

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to write an entire write to a line of a file, not new lines in powershell.  I add items to the array using $array += $newitem (which works), yet when it adds the full array to the file (I've tried both streamwriter and out-file with append), it adds each item as a new line.

**Pseudocode:**

First round 1 then 2 then 3 are added to $array.
Second round, which starts $array back at an empty state, 4 then 5 then 6 are added to $array.
Then I output the data.  The result in a file:

```
1,
2,
3
4,
5,
6
```

The output I want:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the -join operator? Assuming your first array has 1,2,3 added to it:

```
$array = ("1","2","3")
$array -join ','
```

What that does is take each element, and slaps the ',' character in between them. You can store the result of the $array -join ',' into another variable, then output it later if you need to. That would look like this:

$foo = $array -join ','

// do a bunch of stuff

// output $foo here to the command line, or do whatever else with it\

$foo

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like you shouldn't be using an array from the way you describe things. What you may want to try instead is to use a string instead like:

```
[string]$Line="$Line,$NewItem"
```

As a string it will just add the comma and the new item to the end of the string.

Are you trying to manually build a CSV or something? There may be better ways to go about what you are doing.